# How do I iterate through object inside of conditional statement in pugjs?

Tags: iteration, conditional-statements, pugjs

How do I iterate through the object "item" inside of this if statement in pugjs?  I want to skip over the given "item" if the identicalCount is not there (I have other functions carried out should it skip over this loop.

```
each item in testResultData
    if !item.identicalCount
      //need to iterate to next object "item" in testResultData here...
```

I have been unsuccessful in finding documentation or answers to this on stackOverflow or pugjs.org in regards to this.

Comment: There's no problem with the code here, could you please post the JSON that is sent to this template and the res.render statement?